# What does kernel radius mean?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm taking computer vision class. I don't understand the concept of kernel radius.

```
// Convolve the kernel at each pixel
        for(I =-radius;i<=radius;i++)
            for(j=-radius;j<=radius;j++)
```

What does radius do here?
[image]
Say the picture above is a kernel, then where is the radius?

Comment: Visit [THIS PAGE](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/) and scroll down to the 'Kernel' section

Comment: radius in this case refers to the size of the kernel window. In your case the radius of the kernel is '3'

Comment: Moreover, in the code that you have shared you can change the radius to any *odd* integer of your choice.

Comment: you know that you can draw straight lines and rectangles on a computer right?

Comment: @JeruLuke that is not correct. you are talking about the kernel width. just look at his loops. if you would use 3 as a radius he would iterate over the interval of [-3;3]. That's 9x9 pixels. The radius in his example is 1.5 which gives us an interval of [-1;1] in integers. Why do you think it is named radius? Since when is radius and diameter the same?

Comment: @JeruLuke the link you referred is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you see that the for loop which will perform the convolution of your data with a kernel, goes over a square of coordinates (-`kernel radius`, -`kernel radius`)=lower left corner to (`kernel radius`, `kernel radius`)=right, upper corner, i.e. the edge length of the square will be 2*`kernel radius`.

This means, the support (the region, where the kernel can be non-zero) is limited to this centered square.

A square-shaped area is used because the grid is square and for performance reasons. To treat every direction equal, the kernel would theoretically rather have a disc-like support. A disc with a radius of value `kernel radius` would look very similar to the used square-shaped support. That's what's behind the name `kernel radius`.

So in short: The `kernel radius` is the limit on absolute(x) and absolute(y) of the support of the convolution kernel. It's very similar to limiting the convolution kernel to a support of a disc of radius = `kernel radius`, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks for clear up the concept.  Really appreciate it.